# Calling variables from another function in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello guys I am trying to call some variables from a function that exist in another file. That function use `export` so I am importing it in the other js and in the end the variable value from new js returns `undefined`;

here I create user_id and token and dispatch to userCredentials()

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return axios.post(SIGNIN_URL, { email, password }).then((response) => {
      var { user_id, token } = response.data;
      dispatch(authUser(user_id));
      dispatch(userCredentials(user_id, token));
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(addAlert("Could not log in."));
    });
  };
}
```

This is the function I am exporting from **app/actions/authActions.js**

```
export function userCredentials(user_id, token) {
  user_id,
  token, 
  console.log('my token is ' + token); // I call this function when I Log In and generate the token value and it shows me in console.
}
```

Now I am importing that function and use the variables inside **app/actions/jobsActions.js**

```
import {userCredentials} from './authActions';


export function createJob(title, token, user_id) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    console.log('token is ' + token); // when I call this function here I get undefined
      return axios.post(JOBS_URL(user_id), { title }, {
        headers: { authorization: token }
      }).then((response) => {
        var { user_id, token } = credentials;
        dispatch(addJob(response.data.job));
      }).catch((err) => {
        dispatch(addAlert("Couldn't create job."));
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Why is your function taking in user_id and not doing anything with it? Then console.log'ing the token...this function is very pointless.

Also why list user_id and token followed by commas before console.log? That's not valid JS

Comment: @PaulBrittain what do you mean the function is in user_id? I am using email address as encrypted and that encryption is user_id is not like id: 1, id: 2, is more like this 5ad8a2be524d827b19395a01

Comment: I mean the only thing `userCredentials ` is doing is taking in a user_id and a token, and console.log'ing.. why bother with a function?

Comment: @PaulBrittain to export it and import it after that. I don't think I can do this from the function where I am actually create them --- see updated code

Comment: @PaulBrittain do you have an idea how to store this two values in an AsyncStorage and then use them in the other function?

Comment: You're using redux so why not set those in the store..? Also you probably need to touch up on your javascript because the way you're trying to access those variables will never work. If anything, userCredentials should be setting variables that you'd want to export/import but it really shouldn't be doing that when you're using redux.